# Firebase Functions : How to get IP address from client?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to get the IP address from the client in the firebase function by using javascript . Why do I need IP?  To make whitelist IPs that can access my functions.

my goal:  **access my function by IP address**

I tried to use this method but didn't work for me it give me 'undefined' :

```
exports.getIP = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
var call = req.ip
console.log(call);
res.send(call);
});

exports.getIP = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  var call = req.headers['x-forwarded-for']
  console.log(call);
  res.send(call);
  });
```

Here when I call req.headers :

[image]

Comment: `x-forwarded-for` is a valid header and seems to be working. You can also try using `x-appengine-user-ip` header. At worst, can you `console.log(req.headers)` and share the output?

Comment: @Dharmaraj I updated question, I tried to run 'x-appengine-user-ip' but it give me undefined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both the `'x-forwarded-for'` and `x-appengine-user-ip` headers will be added when you deploy your Cloud functions. It seems you are using Firebase Functions emulator which runs on localhost (since the *host* header is `localhost:5001`). You can try deploying the function and logging the IP.

> The `X-Forwarded-For` (XFF) header is a de-facto standard header for identifying the originating IP address of a client connecting to a web server through *an HTTP proxy or a load balancer*.

> The `X-Appengine-User-IP` is set by App Engine.

When you emulate functions locally there is no proxy in between hence those headers are missing.

References:

- [MDN - X-Forwarded-For](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Forwarded-For)
- [App Engine Headers](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/reference/request-headers)

Comment: Finally, It works you saved me from thinking a lot. As you said x-forwarded-for added after deploying my Cloud functions.